# How to do the integrals over the multivariate delta function?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, integration, mathematics, calculus, dirac-delta-distributions

How to do this integration?

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dq\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dp \; \delta(E-\frac{p^2}{2m}-\frac{k}{2}q^2)= 2\pi\sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}$$

I obtained the result using Mathematica, I am not even sure it is correct. Anyways, I'd love to know how one can evaluate this by hand. I am familiar with the Delta function and the identities on how to evaluate those integrals over infinities.

Comment: It's not any different from doing one integral at a time. Just ignore the $dq$ integral and treat $q$ as a constant while doing the $dp$ integral.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: I firmly believe that integrals arising in statistical physics like this one should be posted here. I've often been told on Mathematics to ask physicists because mathematicians don't do integrals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to solve this - and particularly, the way that minimizes the chances of messing it up - is to switch over to a single coordinate that inside the delta function. In your case it's easy - just choose an appropriate polar representation: set
\begin{align}
q& = A\, r\cos(\theta)\\
p& = B\, r\sin(\theta),
\end{align}
and require that $\frac{1}{2m}A^2 = \frac{k}{2}B^2$ (via e.g. $A=1$, $B=1/\sqrt{mk}$) to get
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm dp\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm dq \,\delta(E-\frac{1}{2m}p^2-\frac{k}{2}q^2)
&=
B\int_0^\infty r\:\mathrm dr \int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm d\theta \, \delta(E-\frac{1}{2m}r^2)
\\&=
\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{mk}}\int_0^\infty  \delta(E-\frac{1}{2m}r^2) r\:\mathrm dr.
\end{align}
From there, change variables to $u=r^2/2m$, so that $\mathrm du=r\,\mathrm dr/m$, which gives you 
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm dp\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm dq \,\delta(E-\frac{1}{2m}p^2-\frac{k}{2}q^2)
&=
\frac{2m\pi}{\sqrt{mk}}\int_0^\infty  \delta(E-u) \mathrm du,
\end{align}
and that reduces to the result you quote since $\int_0^\infty  \delta(E-u) \mathrm du=1$ whenever $E>0$.

Comment: The way you chose the substitution, I actually got $\frac{k}{2} A^2 = \frac{B^2}{2m}$ and therefor $A=1$ and $B=\sqrt{km}$. Anyways, I was able to follow your steps and will definitely add this substitution to my tool box. One last question, do we need $E>0$ or is it $E\geq 0$ still sufficient for the last integral to give 1?

Comment: @Marsl The delta function at the edges of domains isn't particularly well defined - but it's only one point and it can be set at will without changing the results of whatever further integration you're doing over $E$ later. If you get to a point where that choice matters, you've probably done something wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The idea here is to use the following property of the delta function:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(f(x))g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\sum_{r}\frac{g(r)}{|f'(r)|}$$

Where the sum ranges over all values of $r$ such that $f(r)=0$. This is basically just what happens when you change variables to perform the integral.

If we let $f(p)=p^2/2m+kq^2/2-E$, then $f=0$ at $p_{\pm}=\pm\sqrt{2mE-kmq^2}$, which is real only for $kq^2\leq 2E$. We also have $|f'(p_{\pm})|=\sqrt{(2E-kq^2)/m}$, so long as $kq^2\leq 2E$. Thus, we can perform the $p$ integral to get

$$2\int_{-\sqrt{2E/k}}^{\sqrt{2E/k}}\mathrm{d}q\,\sqrt{\frac{m}{2E-kq^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{4m}{k}}\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}$$

Which is exactly what you got!

I hope this helped!

Comment: Hi, there, thanks for the help! I am not familiar with the formula you gave there but found it on wikipedia. Unfortunately, I still miss some points. 1.The 2 in front is because we have 2 terms contributing to the sum, namely $p_+$ and $p_-$?  2. I suppose that $g(r) = 1$ ? and 3. how did you get the new limits $\sqrt{2E/k}$ for the q-integral?

Comment: You are exactly correct. The factor of $2$ is due to the fact that we have two terms contributing the same amount. In this case $g(r)=1$, since no function multiplies the delta function in the original integral. Finally, the bounds $\pm\sqrt{2E/k}$ come from the fact that the argument can only be set to zero if the value of $q$ is within those bounds. It's important to always be careful to check that a solution to the delta function exists, since that solution defines the domain of integration once you've done the first integral. (Also I assumed everyhwere that $E\geq 0$.)